# Невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из объекта класса в "const int"

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++

Имеется класс Falling_shapes с методом `void add(const Body&)`. *(для компактности некоторые члены и методы опущены)*

```
class Falling_shapes
{
public:
  void add(const Body&);
};
```

Также имеется класс, который в деструкторе вызывает эту функцию, передавая в качестве параметра свой член типа `Body`

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    Falling_shapes* const sh;
    Body body;
public:
    virtual ~Shape(){ sh->add(body); }
    /*...*/
};
```

При сборке появилось 9 одинаковых ошибок
`"void Falling_shapes::add(const int)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "Body" в "const int"`    в месте вызова функции в деструкторе.
Пробовал передавать параметр функции через не константную ссылку (изменив сигнатуру функции), тогда появлялось несколько одинаковых ошибок `Функция не принимает 1 аргументов`. Все нужные заголовки с объявлениями подключены были. На всю программу есть только одна функция  с таким именем. От класса `Shape` публично наследуются 7 классов, которые не переопределяют деструктор. Класс `Falling_shapes` объявлялся и определялся в разных файлах.
Определение метода `add`:

```
void Falling_shapes::add(const Body& _body)
{
    shapes.push_back(_body);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != _body.size(); ++i)
        coords.insert(std::make_pair(_body[i].Y, _body[i].X));
}
```

Comment: Перед тем, как задавать вопрос, следовало убедиться, что приведенный код позволяет воспроизвести заявленную ошибку. А лучше сразу добавить ссылку на онлайн компилятор, где она демонстрируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в неправильно поставленных директивах `#include`.
Файл *"Body.h"*

```
#include "Falling_shapes.h"
```

Файл *"Falling_shapes.h"*

```
#include "Body.h"
```

Проблема решилась объявлением класса и убиранием директив `#include`
Файл *"Body.h"* теперь

```
//#include "Falling_shapes.h"
class Falling_shapes;
```

*"Falling_shapes.h"* остался без изменений

```
#include "Body.h"
```

В `.cpp` файлы реализации так же были включены нужные заголовки.
Файл *"Body.cpp"*

```
#include "Body.h"
#include "Falling_shapes.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой минимальный код работает без ошибок:

```
class Body {
};

class Falling_shapes
{
public:
    void add(const Body&) {
        std::cout << "add" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Shape
{
protected:
    Falling_shapes* const sh = new Falling_shapes();
    Body body;
public:
    virtual ~Shape() { 
        sh->add(body); 
    }
};

int main() {
    Shape* p = new Shape();
    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

т.е. вы чего-то не дописали нам тут :)

попробуйте для начала создать работоспособный пример с урезанной функциональностью

Comment: Пока готовил пример чуть не лишился половины кода. А так проблему уже решил. Проблема была в директивах #include, чего я совсем не ожидал. Пока готовил пример, поместил всё в один файл и программа начала компилироваться. Спасибо за то, что направили в правильное русло :)